# Apply gdal_rasterize with spatilite

Tags: gdal, sql, spatialite

I am trying to rasterize a spatialite database using gdal_rasterize. I am using gdalUtils in R to do so and have run the following

`gdal_rasterize -burn 1 -sql SELECT * FROM plants WHERE binomial="Albies alba" -ts -dialect SQLITE 129600 64800 -ot Byte ./plants.sqlite ./test_r.tif`

This is giving me a status 1 error and I am wondering if I my SQL syntax is wrong.

Comment: SQL part must be enclosed, on Linux probably between single quotes. This part `WHERE binomial="Albies alba"` is not correct SQL (means "where binomial equals the value of a column named "Albies alba"". Strings in SQL appear between single quotes. Because you will then have single quotes between single quotes the inner ones must be escaped but I do not know how it goes on Linux. Maybe with a caret ^'

Comment: also `-ts 129600 64800 -dialect SQLITE` seems a better syntax for the gdal command.